# Vb6 application CRUD Windows' registry 32 or 64 bits

Tags: vb6, registry, 32bit-64bit

I have an application in vb6, which reads, writes in the Windows registry. It works well for devices with 32-bit 64-bit but did not find the path.
 Anyone know of some code that allows me to read and write registers 32 and 64 regardless.
 I'm using the code of this page.

http://www.elguille.info/vb/utilidades/queryreg/QueryReg3.htm

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to read up on [Accessing an Alternate Registry View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the adjacent, related topics at MSDN.

There are tons of VB6 examples around, but it helps if you know how to "ask" (search0 for them.  Vocabulary counts!

They "key" (no pun intended) you'll want to look at using is `KEY_WOW64_64KEY`

You should be able to combine this with most code examples you already have that are based on API calls.